# Highcharts - linear regression that changes according to vertical line

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linear-regression

I have a question that is a follow-up on this question here: [Two synchronized vertical lines in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64645784/two-synchronized-vertical-lines-in-highcharts)

I just came across this nice example of how to draw a linear fit in `Highcharts`: https://codepen.io/mushigh/pen/ZEQxXOz

Now, my question is: using this [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jwtLc379/), how could I implement linear fits that change according to the drag of the line?

What I am looking for is:

- Linear fit from the beginning until the first vertical line;
- Linear fit from the first until the second vertical line;
- And linear fit from the second vertical line until the end.

Since the vertical lines are draggable, I am not sure this is possible?

---

**Update:**

This extension might get things easier: https://github.com/streamlinesocial/highcharts-regression

Comment: Before I start coding the answer I would like to be sure about your requirement - would you like to render the regression line between those two annotations and keep them draggable?

Comment: That is correct.. but I need only the vertical lines to be draggable.. and then the linear regression changes as the lines move

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am going to update a reprex of what I have tried so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt, please take a look at it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/prq563Ly/

1. We need to add the regression line on the initial chart load:

   ```
     events: {
       load() {
         let chart = this,
           newData = [];

         chart.series[0].data.forEach(d => {
           if (d.category > firstInitialX && d.category < secondInitialX) {
             newData.push([d.category, d.x])
           }
         });

         chart.addSeries({
           regression: true,
           name: 'Test input',
           color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
           data: newData,
           regressionSettings: {
             enableMouseTracking: false
           }
         })
       }
     }
   ```
2. We need to update the regression line data after dragging the annotations:

   ```
   Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function(chart) {
     if (chart !== thisChart) {
       chart.annotations[index].update({
         labels: [{
           point: {
             x: newX
           }
         }],
         shapes: [{
           points: [{
             x: newX,
             xAxis: 0,
             y: 0
           }, {
             x: newX,
             xAxis: 0,
             y: 1000
           }]
         }]
       });


     }

     let firstAnnotation = chart.annotations[0].shapes[0].points[0].x;
     let secondAnnoation = chart.annotations[1].shapes[0].points[0].x
     chart.series.forEach(s => {
       if (s.data.length !== 500) {
         s.remove()
       }
     })

     chart.series[0].data.forEach(d => {
       if (d.category > firstAnnotation && d.category < secondAnnoation) {
         newData.push([d.category, d.x])
       }
     });
     chart.addSeries({
       regression: true,
       name: 'Test input',
       color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
       data: newData,
       regressionSettings: {
         enableMouseTracking: false
       }
     })
   });
   }
   ```

Let me know what do you think about this kind of solution. Feel free to improve it.